# About overlapping of Time Series on X-axis

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, data-science

I have plotted the timeseries of 5 min on x-axis but it's getting overlapped. Can you suggest the updates to be made?
given below is my output

[image]

given below is my code:

```
plt.plot(s1[0:289]['Timeseries'],s1[0:5762][' CCN Number Conc'])
plt.xlabel("Time In Minutes")
plt.xticks(rotation=90)
plt.ylabel("Cloud Condensation Number")
plt.title("cloud Condensation Number Vs TimeSeries(5min)")
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Comment: Could you please provide some sample data (e.g., s1) so that one could reproduce your issue?

Comment: Timeseries SS Bin 1 Bin 2 Bin 3 Bin 4 Bin 5 Bin 6 Bin 7 Bin 8 ... Bin 12 Bin 13 Bin 14 Bin 15 Bin 16 Bin 17 Bin 18 Bin 19 Bin 20 CCN Number Conc
0 00:00:00 0.1 3.180000 4.673333 2.116667 1.680000 0.216667 0.116667 0.013333 0.000000 ... 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.0 0.0 0 0 0 15.810967
1 00:05:00 0.3 34.680000 74.790000 66.453333 79.013333 11.980000 4.220000 0.613333 0.133333 ... 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.0 0.0 0 0 0 358.401000

Answer (score 0):

Try using this:

```
plt.setp(ax.get_xticklabels(), rotation=30, horizontalalignment='right')
fig.tight_layout()
# you can play around with rotation.
```

Second way:

```
fig.autofmt_xdate()
```

Comment: Dear Sir, The answer one provided by you did not work out. with my code ,rather it gave error at 'ax.' not deifined